# Set the Send and Cancel button to something else than white on a white background in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Sometimes the Send and Cancel buttons appears white so they are almost invisible on the white background on the MFMailComposeViewController. The instance of MFMailComposeViewController is created after pressing a UITextView with dataDetectorTypes .Link so I could not immediately access the instance before in the viewDidLoad function see below:

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController {
    override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {        
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
     }

    override public func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.translucent = false
        navigationBar.opaque = false
    }
}
```

How can I set the default colors on the buttons on the MFMailComposeViewController and avoid to mess up the navigationbars in the rest of the app?

As it is now the barTintColor is not set the first time going in. But the second time around it is set to blackColor, i guess from the viewWillDisappear call from the previous instance.

Comment: Didi you try to put it in `UINavigationController` (that is already styled as you need) before presenting it? Even if you use different `UINavigationController` in your app, you can create another one just for `MFMailSomposeViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to catch the URL interaction from the TextView be setting the delegate and then set the tintColor to the navigationbar to the defaultTintColor.

```
extension ContactViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        if URL.absoluteString.containsString("mailto:") {
            let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            let emailString = URL.absoluteString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("mailto:", withString: "")
            mailVC.setToRecipients([emailString])
            mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
            let defaultTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122/255, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)
            mailVC.navigationBar.tintColor = defaultTintColor
            mailVC.navigationBar.translucent = false
            mailVC.navigationBar.opaque = false
            self.presentViewController(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
        else if URL.absoluteString.containsString("tel") {
            if let url = NSURL(string: URL.absoluteString) where UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
                return true //let the system handle with a telprompt
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

extension ContactViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError?) {
        switch result.rawValue {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            print("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
            print("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            print("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
            if let error = error {
                print("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first.. do not use 
**UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()**

If you have a storyboard with a UINavigationController set the tint color there to your UINavigationBar.

There is only one navigationBar for each UINavigationController

You can't handle your color with that ugly appearance tool for all cases. Some controllers (MailComposer, PhotoRoll,...) are using black BarButtons some are tinted in white.

If you are using appearance ... all bars are effected (only new created bars, not the ones in memory)

Comment: I discarded the use of extension of the MFMailComposeViewController. And cought the .Link interaction manually in a way that I had an instance of the mailComposeVC to configure.